# When will a spilling process stop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

A mapper output is temporarily stored in circular buffer (in memory). The default buffer size is 100 Mb. When the buffer is 80% filled, A spilling process will start. (http://grepalex.com/2012/09/24/map-partition-sort-spill/) 
When does this spilling (to one spill) stop/complete?
Will it stop after a spill of fixed size is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Question. Let me try to explain step by step.

1. The map will write (using Mapper.Context.write()) its output into a circular in-memory buffer (MapTask.MapOutputBuffer).
2. When the buffer crosses the default threshold limit of 80% all the data that is in the buffer will be spilled to the disk.
3. So, assume that mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb is set to 100 MB and mapreduce.map.sort.spill.percent is set to 0.8.
4. Now when the data in the buffer gets to say 85 MB which is more than 80% then all of the 85 MB will be spilled to a single split file.
5. Multiple threads are used to spill the data to the disk.
6. Spilling works in a separate thread allowing mapper to continue functioning and processing input data while spilling happens.
7. So this scenario of the circular buffer crossing 80% of its size will occur again and a new spill file will be created.

Reference links:
[Link 1](http://ercoppa.github.io/HadoopInternals/AnatomyMapReduceJob.html) [Link 2](http://0x0fff.com/hadoop-mapreduce-comprehensive-description/)

Answer (score 0):

Here spill means it is spilling to local disk(not hdfs) where the reducer would pick it up. The spills are written in a round robin fashion to the directories specified by the mapred.local.dir property. The spill would stop when all the map outputs are written to disk.